# Changing background property through jQuery is causing trouble in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

This is really weird how Safari behaves and I don't know why it adds extra properties that is causing me a lot of trouble in a project I'm working on.

The test is pretty simple, here's a little fiddle:

```js
function clickme() {
 $('.container').css('background', "red");
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
<button onclick="clickme();">Click me!</button>
```

You will see that in Chrome or Firefox, it will add `background: red` as you would expect, now in Safari adds this:

```
style="background-color: red; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;"
```

This is causing me trouble by not allowing me to override a pre-defined CSS style of `background-image`, I need to set **background: '#color'** mandatory. Otherwise the `background-image` will always be over the `background-color` even though it's inline in the element. Safari is not my friend right now.

Is there any solution into this? I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://caniuse.com

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an issue using shorthand `background` property inline. Try separating the shorthand `background` property out to its individual properties:

```
$('.container').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Or you could try using a class with your `background` property:

```
.bg {
    background: red
}

$('.container').addClass('bg');
```

Comment: The problem is that I need it to be "background: red" as in Chrome or Firefox :/ It looks like a bug in Safari, right? now, it only happens using jQuery because if you use plane Javascript using setAttribute, it doesn't happen.. so this is jQuery's fault.

Comment: i can't do that either, it needs to be inline-style. Thanks tho for trying to help.

Comment: @msqar It seems like it's not supported with inline styles. Hope you find a workaround :)

Comment: Yea, for now i had to add "background-image: none" in the inline style for Safari only, but i don't know, im not yet convinced of this way to fix it.